# Angular Material Multi Progress Bar using multiple colors

Tags: angular, angular-material, progress-bar

What is the best way to achieve a Multi Progress Bar using Angular Material?

[image: Multi Progress Bar]

If it is not possible using Angular Material, can somebody please suggest me of any good graphing libraries that can be integrated with Angular to achieve the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of an easy way to do that staying inside Angular Material.

The easiest way is probably to go down the `flex` road, with some css styling.

I made a very basic [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dkuczj) to showcase the idea. Then you can CSS style all of this and get what you want.

Another way to go is to build the bar using SVG. You can achieve more powerful effects, but it comes at the cost of writing a bit of SVG yourself (basically `rect` elements, and then you can improve on that).

**Edit**: OP's fine-tuning of the Stackblitz to match the initial image: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u2stx8.

Comment: I extended this to get something like this

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u2stx8

Comment: yeah nice, that's the idea. Then you use `[fxFlex]` with dynamic value and you have your progress bar. I edited the answer with your link to have a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve a two-colour material progress bar and then you can play with `buffer` property to add some fireworks.

The first step is to add progress bar in html. I used "accent" as a color.

`<mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate" color="accent"></mat-progress-bar>`

Then you have to import `MatProgressBarModule` into you app.module.ts file

Next, you have to define the accent colour with your favourites colours in styles.scss:

```
$accent: (
  50: red,
  100: blue,
  200: green,
  contrast: (
    50: pink
  )
);

$my-app-accent:  mat-palette($accent, 50, 100, 200);
$my-app-theme: mat-light-theme($my-app-primary, $my-app-accent);
```

If you have any problems during theming you angular material, check out manual: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming